# Start-Transcript and save in SharePoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am trying to save the output file of the Start-Transcript in the cloud and exactly in shared documents. As -path string cannot be different than local on your drive I tried to define the ShareFile location(I do not want to map any drive):

```
Folder1 = "Shared Documents"
$SharedFolder = Get-PNPFolder -URL $Folder1
```

Then I tried to use it as output for a path:

```
Start-Transcript -path $SharedFolder
```

Which of course it fails. Every time it is adding in the location where the .ps1 file is a folder path like this:
ps1 is in C:\aaa\ so it is adding a location like this c:\aaa\sharedfolder\transcriptfile.txt

Of course, I could use copy after and use method PNP-AddFile but there is one trick when the file is in use it doesn't want to copy it to the location which I tried to sort.
I used this to copy after the Stop-Transcription

```
Add-PnPFile -Path ".\transcriptfile.txt" -Folder $Folder1
```

This command working when the script end and I run it separately after.

Maybe someone can help me differently than this?

Thank you

Comment: `Start-Transcript`'s path does not need to be local, `Start-Transcript -Path '\\server\share\folder\out.txt'` can work just fine. Sharepoint folders aren't really a filesystem like an SMB share though.

Comment: `Add-PnPFile` can take a `Stream` input, so if you really want to upload as soon as possible, you could start a `StreamReader` process to watch the transcript file and stream new lines to your shared file. It will probably be easier to just mount the folder temporarily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only workaround I found is to add a Function to the .ps1 file.

I added Function with

```
Add-PnPFile
```

Which looks like this:

```
Function CopyFile {
Add-PnPFile -path ".\filename.txt" -folder "Shared Documents"
}
```

I added it before the script Exits.
Don't know why standalone code won't work before.